# YouTube autoplay with mute

Tags: javascript, html, youtube, autoplay

I want to autoplay videos that are muted on my website. I found some code which seemed to work, but it doesn't. Why doesn't this javascript and HTML code work?

```
<div id="player"></div>

<script>
  // 2. This code loads the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
  var tag = document.createElement('script');
  tag.src = "http://www.youtube.com/player_api";
  var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

  // 3. This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player)
  //    after the API code downloads.
  var player;
  function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
      playerVars: { 'autoplay': 1, 'controls': 1,'autohide':1,'wmode':'opaque' },
      videoId: 'RDfjXj5EGqI',
      events: {
        'onReady': onPlayerReady}
    });
  }

  // 4. The API will call this function when the video player is ready.
  function onPlayerReady(event) {
    event.target.mute();
  } </script>
```

jsFiddle for testing: https://jsfiddle.net/qswpr8tL/

Thanks!

Comment: Can you check the YouTube API docs? I'm sure there is an option to add to `playerVars`.

Answer (score 0):

Please build your onReady handler just like that:

```
var player;
// ...
function onPlayerReady(event) {
  player.mute();
}
```

According [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference) you have to call `mute` method on `player` object.